# No sound using Delphi and DirectX on Windows 10

Tags: delphi, audio, directx

I've a problem with using DirectX (DirectSound) on Windows 10. I'me changing some legacy code that used DirectX (DirectX 9 I think) and run on Windows XP.

Everything is still working great on Windows XP but I can't get a sound on Windows 10.

The application uses these files: DXUTIL.PAS (Original ObjectPascal conversion made by: Boris V.), lzexpand.pas (Author: Vadim Bodrov) and DirectSound.pas (DirectX 9.0 Delphi / FreePascal adaptation by Alexey Barkovoy).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
sndgwait : PSound;
begin
InitSB(Handle);
LoadWave(sndgwait,   'D:\game\EXP01.wav', 1);
StartSound(sndgwait, false);
end;

function LoadWave(var Sound: PSound; fn : string; conc : integer) : boolean;
var
cbData, cbdata1 : DWORD;
pd1 : pointer;
hfile : longint;
vreopenbuff : TOFStruct;
begin
hfile := LZOpenFile(PAnsiChar(fn), vreopenbuff, OF_READ);
if hfile < 0 then begin result := false; exit; end;
cbdata := LZSeek(hfile, 0, 2);  // file size
LZSeek(hfile, 0, 0);            //back to the start of the wav
getmem(pd1, cbdata);
LZRead(hfile,  pd1, cbdata);
LZClose(hfile);
if conc < 1 then conc := 1;
result := ParseWaveData(Sound, conc, cbdata, pd1);
end;

function ParseWaveData(var Sound : PSound; conc : integer; cbdata : dword; pd1 : pointer) :  boolean;
var
pWaveHeader: PWAVEFORMATEX;
pDSB: IDirectSoundBuffer;
dsBD: TDSBUFFERDESC;
rr : longint;
begin
if lpDS = nil then begin
result := false;
exit;
end;
Sound := PSNDOBJ(LocalAlloc(LPTR, SizeOf(TSNDOBJ) + (conc-1) * SizeOf(IDirectSoundBuffer)));
Sound^.iAlloc := conc;
Sound^.cbWaveSize := 0;
Sound^.pbWaveData := nil;
pwaveHeader := nil;
Sound^.pbData := pd1;
Sound^.cbSize := cbdata;
if DSParseWaveResource(pd1, pWaveHeader, Sound^.pbWaveData, Sound^.cbWaveSize) then begin
ZeroMemory(@dsBD, SizeOf(dsBD));
dsBD.dwSize := SizeOf(dsBD);
dsBD.dwFlags := DSBCAPS_STATIC or DSBCAPS_GETCURRENTPOSITION2 or DSBCAPS_CTRLFREQUENCY orDSBCAPS_CTRLPAN or DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME;//DSBCAPS_CTRLDEFAULT or
dsBD.lpwfxFormat := pWaveHeader;
dsBD.dwBufferBytes := Sound^.cbWaveSize;

if lpDS.CreateSoundBuffer(dsBD, pDSB, nil) = DS_OK then begin
if not DSFillSoundBuffer(pDSB, Sound^.pbWaveData, dsBD.dwBufferBytes) then begin
pDSB._Release;
pDSB := nil;
end;
Sound^.Buffers[0] := pDSB;
for rr := 1 to conc - 1 do begin
lpDS.DuplicateSoundBuffer(Sound^.Buffers[0], Sound^.Buffers[rr]);
end;
end else begin
pDSB := nil;
SndObjDestroy(Sound);
Sound := nil;
end;

end;
Result := Sound <> nil;
end;

function StartSound(Sound: PSound; Loop: boolean = false; waitforend: boolean = false): boolean;
begin
if Loop then
StartSound := SndObjPlay(Sound, DSBPLAY_LOOPING)
else
 StartSound := SndObjPlay(Sound, 0);
if waitforend and not loop then
while SoundPlaying(Sound) do Application.ProcessMessages;
  
end;

function SndObjPlay(pSO: PSNDOBJ; dwPlayFlags: DWORD): Boolean;
var
pDSB: IDirectSoundBuffer;
begin
Result := FALSE;
if pSO = nil then
begin
exit;
end;
if ((dwPlayFlags and DSBPLAY_LOOPING) = 0) or (pSO^.iAlloc = 1) then
begin
pDSB := SndObjGetFreeBuffer(pSO);
if (pDSB <> nil) then
Result := SUCCEEDED(pDSB.Play(0, 0, dwPlayFlags));
end else
Result:= FALSE;
end;
```

All values in ParseWaveData call are correct I think (no nil values).

I'm not gething any errors. Just there is no sound.

What can be a problem here?

Or are there other ways to use DirectX for sound in this old app on windows 10? Any example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot guarantee this is the fix, it is worth a try. I had a lot of issues with Windows 10 sound, often it seemed at random! Switching apps disabled sound from background apps, game programming wouldn't make a peep, even playing music to see if I had the right track with CD burning software was broken, Netflix breaking sound until I rebooted, wireless headphones not working or volume way too low. Infuriating. You might not be wrestling control from whatever has current priority because of an W10 April 2018 change and just not had the issues I've had.

Anyway, this is worth a try:

> Right-click the Sound Icon in the bottom right of task bar. Click
> Playback or Audio Devices. Right-click the speaker icon that appears
> in the settings screen. Click Properties from the pop-up menu. Click
> the Advanced tab on the Speakers Properties screen. Uncheck the boxes
> for Allow applications to take exclusive control and Give exclusive
> mode applications priority.

Comment: I've tried to check those things, but with no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this. At the end it wasn't anything with DirectX.

hfile := LZOpenFile(PAnsiChar(fn), vreopenbuff, OF_READ);

Parameter "fn" (string) that was input to the procedure was wrong. Something messes up. The file name was incorrect, so file that should be played was empty. Nothing to do with DirectX.  I've replaced above command with:

hfile := LZOpenFile(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(fn)), vreopenbuff, OF_READ);

Now it is working.